# Is my approach toward GLM correct?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I'm studying behavior types versus individual characteristics (age, gender, marital status, education, physical handicap) and classified them into binary data except for age.
Example :

- Gender (0:Female; 1:male)
- Marital status (0:no; 1:yes)
- Education (college-graduated: 1;otherwise: 0)

I describe data on this form :

```
              Behavior 1         Behavior 2      Behavior 3
              Mean    SD         Mean    SD      Mean    SD
Age           37.05  15.8        36.2   15.05    30.07   13  
Gender        0.49   0.501       0.4    0.49     0.67    0.5
Education     0.03   0.185       0.04   0.20     0       0
```

We these data we could say for example that behavior 3 is more likely to occur when the age is relatively decreased and gender effect (male) comparing to other behaviors, but still speculation. But it allows me to  have an idea about what variables to include in GLM. 
After that I'm trying to model behavior by converting behavior 3 appearance into (0, 1) for each individual

```
id   Behavior3 Age Gender
1       0      19  M
....
499     1      45  F

model1=glm(Behavior3 ~ Age + Gender, family=binomial)
summary(model1)
```